# How to post and access the data using jquery ajax in asp.net webforms?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

Here is my current code:

Here is for default.aspx

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="mydiv">

    </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Default2.aspx',
                data: "{ 'name': '" + "randel" + "' }",

                type: "POST",
                success: function () {

                    // alert('insert was performed.');
                    $("#mydiv").empty();

                    $("#mydiv").load("Default2.aspx #div");

                },
                error: function (data, status, jqXHR) { alert(jqXHR); }
            });

        })
    </script>
</body>
```

Then for Default2.aspx, I want to access the data like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Request.Form["name"].ToString();

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like you want to use **WebMethod** in ASP.NET:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'Default2.aspx/HelloWorld',
                data: "{ 'name': '" + "randel" + "' }",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    // alert('insert was performed.');
                    $("#mydiv").empty();
                    $("#mydiv").html(data);
                },
                error: function (data, status, jqXHR) { alert(jqXHR); }
            });
        });
```

and in your code behind you should do this:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string HelloWorld(string name)
{
string message = "Hello " + name;
return message;
}
```

WebMethods are in some kind better than doing **__doPostBack()** because you controll all client-server traffic using for example jQuery.
More about WebMethods: [here](http://elegantcode.com/2009/02/21/javascript-arrays-via-jquery-ajax-to-an-aspnet-webmethod/) or just google WebMethods ASP.NET.

And If you want to receive some form value you should put it on **$.ajax data** parameter and add the same parameter in **WebMethod**.

**EDITED**

From the code you post I see that you want send from Default.aspx some data to Default2.aspx and load some content from Default2.aspx (#div).

You can do this:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/Default2.aspx",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "html",
                async: false,
                data: { "name": "randel"
                },
                success: function (obj) {
                    // obj will contain the complete contents of the page requested
                    // use jquery to extract just the html inside the body tag
                    $content = $(obj).find('body #div').html();
                    // then update the dialog contents with this and show it
                }
         });
```

And in code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["name"];
    }
```

Comment: No, I want to access the data in the Default2.aspx page not in a webservice but thank you for the immediate reply. Thanks++

Comment: @randelramirez1 Take a look now.

Comment: thank for that solution but will I wanted to use "POST", but thanks++ :D

Comment: You cannot do POST in this case.

Comment: [WebMethod] is an attribute which can be applied to any function of webforms and not just a webservice.