# Ajax POST Data not being sent to the Page_Load method in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms

I am basically trying to send some test values from my javascript function to the Page_Load method in my ASP.NET Web Forms page.

However, when debugged I noticed that the Request data are null and **does not go through the condition**.

Code:

**test.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <input type="button" onclick="senddata()" />
        </div>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function senddata() {
                var testdata = "checkcheck";

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/test.aspx',
                    data: { "data": testdata},
                    success: function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg);
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>
</form>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //doesn't go beyond this when I click the button
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form["data"]))
    {
        string resp = "working";
        Response.Write(resp );
        Response.End();
        return;
    }
}
```

Any idea why the data is not received from the code behind? It's a very simple example and I am wondering why.

Comment: this is not called because page load event will not fired since all the resources are already loaded, create a web service method instead to handle you ajax call

Comment: Page load gets fired. Once when the page is loaded and again when the button is clicked. When the button is clicked, It should go in to the condition as I am sending data. It just doesn't go through the condition. @MidTwo

Comment: try to use another json key, replace "data" with another keyname or inspect the value of your form array

Comment: No luck. The Request.Form keys are empty. I debugged and checked @MidTwo

Comment: again use web method, this is an appropriate implementation for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061959/how-to-post-and-access-the-data-using-jquery-ajax-in-asp-net-webforms

Comment: I've tried your example using JQuery version 2.2.2 and it works perfectly

Comment: Have you tried logging for errors e.g. function senddata() {
                var testdata = "checkcheck";

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Content/PlanningBoardMonth.aspx',
                    data: { "data": testdata},
                    success: function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg);
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        console.log(msg);
                    }
                });
            }

Answer (score 0):

"Request.Form["data"]" initially null , because there is no value in 'data'.
but when you call "test.aspx" on ajax method, it again call pageload event and reset Request.Form["data"] as null.

Instead of this , you should create a web method and call that method in you senddata() function.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all your responses! I managed to fix it by making the following changes:

Inside **~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs**

I changed: `settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;`

To

`settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Off;`

This solved the problem. I have no idea how this configuration got in there. It was added to RouteConfig when I created the project. Hope this helps someone.